# My download script isn't working - file contents are instead being spilled onto the page

Tags: php, download, mime-types

I'm using the following download script to download files uploaded on my server. The files are uploaded fine its just that when they are downloaded instead of getting downloaded the entire contents of the file to be downloaded are spilled out. Click on teh following url to see the problem:

http://iqtechworld.com/demo/download.php?id=28

The following is my download script i.e the entire file itself:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);


ini_set('display_errors', false);
include_once('includes.php');
ini_set('display_errors', false);

function output_file($file, $name, $mime_type='')
{
 /*
 This function takes a path to a file to output ($file), 
 the filename that the browser will see ($name) and 
 the MIME type of the file ($mime_type, optional).

 If you want to do something on download abort/finish,
 register_shutdown_function('function_name');
 */
 if(!is_readable($file)) die('File not found or inaccessible!');

 $size = filesize($file);
 $name = rawurldecode($name);

 /* Figure out the MIME type (if not specified) */
 $known_mime_types=array(
    "pdf" => "application/pdf",
    "txt" => "text/plain",
    "html" => "text/html",
    "htm" => "text/html",
    "exe" => "application/octet-stream",
    "zip" => "application/zip",
    "doc" => "application/msword",
    "xls" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
    "ppt" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
    "gif" => "image/gif",
    "png" => "image/png",
    "jpeg"=> "image/jpg",
    "jpg" =>  "image/jpg",
    "php" => "text/plain"
 );

 if($mime_type==''){
     $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,"."),1));
     if(array_key_exists($file_extension, $known_mime_types)){
        $mime_type=$known_mime_types[$file_extension];
     } else {
        $mime_type="application/force-download";
     };
 };

 @ob_end_clean(); //turn off output buffering to decrease cpu usage

 // required for IE, otherwise Content-Disposition may be ignored
 if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
  ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

 header('Content-Type: ' . $mime_type);
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

 /* The three lines below basically make the 
    download non-cacheable */
 header("Cache-control: private");
 header('Pragma: private');
 header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

 // multipart-download and download resuming support
 if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
 {
    list($a, $range) = explode("=",$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'],2);
    list($range) = explode(",",$range,2);
    list($range, $range_end) = explode("-", $range);
    $range=intval($range);
    if(!$range_end) {
        $range_end=$size-1;
    } else {
        $range_end=intval($range_end);
    }

    $new_length = $range_end-$range+1;
    header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
    header("Content-Length: $new_length");
    header("Content-Range: bytes $range-$range_end/$size");
 } else {
    $new_length=$size;
    header("Content-Length: ".$size);
 }

 /* output the file itself */
 $chunksize = 1*(1024*1024); //you may want to change this
 $bytes_send = 0;
 if ($file = fopen($file, 'r'))
 {
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
    fseek($file, $range);

    while(!feof($file) && 
        (!connection_aborted()) && 
        ($bytes_send<$new_length)
          )
    {
        $buffer = fread($file, $chunksize);
        print($buffer); //echo($buffer); // is also possible
        flush();
        $bytes_send += strlen($buffer);
    }
 fclose($file);
 } else die('Error - can not open file.');

die();
}   


global $FILE_OBJECT;

$one_file = $FILE_OBJECT->get($_GET['id']);
output_file(_config('files_path').$_GET['id'], $one_file['filename'], $one_file['type']);
exit;
```

Comment: The `Content-Type` is `text/html`.

Comment: Don’t use this pseudo-type *application/force-download*; use *[application/octet-stream](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046#section-4.5.1)* instead.

Answer (score 1):

@alex +1, check your web server settings, and also code, maybe there is another `header('Content-type text/html');`

Try use this

```
$file_extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

instead of this

```
$file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,"."),1));
```

Comment: How do I stop teh header from being text HTML? The code posted is the entire page

Answer (score 1):

[Don't](http://www.jtricks.com/bits/content_disposition.html) enclose the filename in quotes for [Content-Disposition](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519).

Comment: There are multiple encoding formats for Content-Disposition’s *filename* parameter value: Initially, MIME did not specify any special format so that the generic attribute value format as plain US-ASCII (see [RFC 2183](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2183#section-2.3) and [RFC 2231](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2231)) and non-ASCII text needs to be encoded according to [RFC 2047](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2047). Later [RFC 5987](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5987) specified the same for non-MIME messages. See also [Test Cases for Content-Disposition](http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/).